# How to draw a line of dots in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Instead of drawing a dashed line as follows:

```
\draw [dashed] (10,1) -- (10,11);
```

I would like to draw a list of dots from `(10,1)` to `(10,11)`, like `.........`, but vertically. Could anyone tell me what to put at the place of `[dashed]`?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27258/how-do-i-write-underline-text-but-with-a-dotted-line

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101262/dotted-lines-in-tikz-with-round-dots/101263#101263

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Use `\draw[dotted]` or `\draw[densely dotted]` or `\draw[loosely dotted]`, for example.

Comment: What I haven't been able to find in the documentation is how to set the space between the dots or how to set the size of the dots for a dotted line.  Do you know where I can find this information?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45275/tikz-get-values-for-predefined-dash-patterns

Comment: How would I use this in a `mynode/.append style=`?

Comment: I used like this ```node/.style={rectangle,draw, dotted, ... ```