# TikZ: Get values for predefined dash patterns

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to get values for predefined dash patterns such as `dotted`? I would like to use those in another program to create the same visual experience. Or do I have to define my own patterns in order to have the same values?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can find the definitions of these and many others in the `tikz.code.tex` file in your distribution (e.g. MikTeX has it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\` )

```
\tikzstyle{solid}=                   [dash pattern=]
\tikzstyle{dotted}=                  [dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off 2pt]
\tikzstyle{densely dotted}=          [dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off 1pt]
\tikzstyle{loosely dotted}=          [dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off 4pt]
\tikzstyle{dashed}=                  [dash pattern=on 3pt off 3pt]
\tikzstyle{densely dashed}=          [dash pattern=on 3pt off 2pt]
\tikzstyle{loosely dashed}=          [dash pattern=on 3pt off 6pt]
\tikzstyle{dashdotted}=              [dash pattern=on 3pt off 2pt on \the\pgflinewidth off 2pt]
\tikzstyle{densely dashdotted}=      [dash pattern=on 3pt off 1pt on \the\pgflinewidth off 1pt]
\tikzstyle{loosely dashdotted}=      [dash pattern=on 3pt off 4pt on \the\pgflinewidth off 4pt]
```

For quick comparison, see the output below:

[image]

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it by about 15 seconds! This is better than my one too, so +1!

Comment: side question: why is the line width referenced using `\the` in the `dashdotted` variants, but not in the `dotted` variants?

Comment: @burnpanck Works both ways so probably just inconsistency.

Comment: PGF employs the full math parser for `dash pattern`. You can even do `dash pattern=on2off3*3on5`, which means `dash pattern=on 2pt off 9pt on 5pt off 2pt on 9pt off 5pt`.

Comment: how do you include those lines in the text? I copied the code but it isn't showing anything.

Comment: @Felipe, You need to add some code 
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        xmin=-2, xmax=3,
        ymin=-2, ymax=3,
        after end axis/.code={
               \draw[dashed,blue,->] (axis cs:1,1) -- (axis cs:2,0);
               }
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comment: @percusse Could you write whole code? thanks in advance