# Dotted line with prescribed density with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to get a dotted line with prescribed density, for instance 10 dots per centimeter, instead of the default?

With Jesse's comment :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\tikzstyle{cm dotted}=[dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off .85mm ]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[cm dotted,line width=.15mm,step=.5] (0,0) grid (5,4) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Still an unwanted shift of half a linewidth. The horizontal and vertical crossing points are not on at the right place. I understand why, but I don't know how fix it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user45209" (any nickname is good).

Comment: This could provide some directions -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45276/34618

Comment: @Jesse, it goes in the good direction. It works but still a unwanted shift of half a linewith.

Comment: You could update your question and give a more specific concerns, experts here are ready to help out.

Comment: I did it and I put a try in the direction you've give.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I *think* this does it. The size of the dot is determined by the line width. The trick is to use a dash of length 0. Which I suppose shouldn't work, but seems to.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}

\tikzset{%
  dots/.style args={#1per #2}{%
    line cap=round,
    dash pattern=on 0 off #2/#1
  }
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1,...,20}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [help lines] grid (4,1);
    \draw [very thick, dots=\i per 1cm] 
      (0,.5) -- (4,.5) 
      node [at start, above right] {\i\ dot\ifnum\i>1s\fi\ per 1cm};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works just fine, the grid is perfect.

Comment: @MarkWibrow How do you make that animated image? (gif I assume). Is it easy to do?

Comment: @macmadness86 open the PDF in [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) with pages as layers, reverse the layers (Layer->Stack->Reverse layer order) and then export to as a `gif`. It is also possible to optimise the animation (Filters>Animation->Optimise for GIF)

Answer (score 2):

With `dotsep` in PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\psset{linewidth=1mm,linestyle=dotted}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,8)
\multido{\i=0+1,\n=.1+.1}{9}{\psline[dotsep=\n](0,\i)(6,\i)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\psset{linewidth=3pt,linestyle=dotted}
\newlength\dotsep
\def\line#1{%
    \dotsep=\dimexpr\dimexpr\psunit-#1\pslinewidth\relax/\numexpr#1-1\relax\relax
    \psline[dotsep=\dotsep](0,1)(6,1)}

\begin{document}
    \foreach \i in {2,...,10}{%
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,2)
        \rput[t](3,1.75){\i\ dots per cm}   
        \line{\i}
    \end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With pstricks I usualy use psgrid and it works find. I know how to do this with metapost. But now I need a tikz command (without foreach), but a style to apply on a line or on a grid.

Comment: @Tarass: OK. The `multido` in my answer is trivial.

Comment: My question was not clear enought.

Comment: Look carefully the difference with Mark Wibrow tikz solution: the first and the last points are not on the grid, it means that it isn't precise enought especialy to make a grid. Exactly the grid pstrciks does and you use for your example. With you solution, the vertical and horizontal lines don't match at crossing points.

Answer (score 0):

The “old” plain TeX actually does this out of the box in one line, without the need of external complex packages:

```
my text\leaders\hbox to 1em{\hss.\hss}\hfill other text
```

Other options are:

- use `\hskip 5cm` instead of `\hfill` to produce a dotted line 5cm long
- use `\hbox to 0.1cm` instead of `hbox to 1em` to change the dot separation to 1mm
- use `\cleaders` instead of `\leaders` to center the leaders, instead of having them alined
- use `\xleaders` to have the leaders expanded to fill out the entire space (in this case the separation provided is a lower limit only).

Comment: I need a tikz style like dotted densely, but with a way to prescribe the number of points in a cm.