# Adding a plus symbol in tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I am in the midst of making a flow chart.

Currently, I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,amsmath}

\tikzstyle{process}=[rectangle,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision}=[diamond,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]

\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick,->,>=stealth]

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node (start) [process] {
        $\text{A}_{it}$
        };

        \node (in1) [process, below of=start] {$\text{B}_{it}$};
        \node (in2) [process, below of=in1] {$\text{C}_{it}$};
        \node (pro2) [decision, right of=in1, xshift=2cm] {$\text{ D}_{it}$};
        \draw [arrow] (start)--(pro2);
        \draw [arrow] (in1)--(pro2);
        \draw [arrow] (in2)--(pro2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

This connects three nodes A, B, C to D.

Now, I wish to create another node, E, to the right of D, but instead of an arrow, I want to add the plus symbol.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: your code is not compileable !

Comment: Hey. You'll significantly increase your chances of someone helping you by posting a code snippet that can be compiled (=includes a `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, etc.). It's just so much easier if we can just copy an paste the code.

Comment: @JouleV  I updated the code to include the definitions. Instead of an arrow to the next node to the right, I wish to use an addition symbol instead. This is because I  wish to show how a variable is calculated.

Comment: your code is still not compileable

Comment: @ChinG Have a look at `decorations.markings`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this ?

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning}

\tikzstyle{process}=[rectangle,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision}=[diamond,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]

\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick,->,>=stealth]

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node (start) [process] {
        $\text{A}_{it}$
        };

        \node (in1) [process, below of=start] {$\text{B}_{it}$};
        \node (in2) [process, below of=in1] {$\text{C}_{it}$};
        \node (pro2) [decision, right= 2cm of in1] {$\text{ D}_{it}$};
        \node (pro3) [decision, right= 2cm of pro2] {$\text{ E}_{it}$};
        \draw [arrow] (start)--(pro2);
        \draw [arrow] (in1)--(pro2);
        \draw [arrow] (in2)--(pro2);
        \draw (pro2) edge node[draw,fill=white,circle]{+} (pro3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

#### addendum

`\tikzstyle` is deprecated since the version 2.10 of tikz, you must use `\tikzset`
which give :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning}

%\tikzstyle{process}=[rectangle,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
%\tikzstyle{decision}=[diamond,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
%
%\tikzstyle{arrow}=[thick,->,>=stealth]

\tikzset{
    process/.style={rectangle,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
    decision/.style={diamond,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30},
        }
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,arrows={-stealth},thick]
        \node (start) [process] { $\text{A}_{it}$ };

        \node (in1) [process, below of=start] {$\text{B}_{it}$};
        \node (in2) [process, below of=in1] {$\text{C}_{it}$};
        \node (pro2) [decision, right= 2cm of in1] {$\text{ D}_{it}$};
        \node (pro3) [decision, right= 2cm of pro2] {$\text{ E}_{it}$};
        \draw [->] (start)--(pro2);
        \draw [->] (in1)--(pro2);
        \draw [->] (in2)--(pro2);
        \draw (pro2) edge node[fill=white]{+} (pro3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please consider stopping to propagate `\tikzstyle` further.

Comment: Yes Andre! Thanks a lot. COuld the plus sign be displayed without the circle?

Comment: @ChinG simply write `\draw (pro2) edge node[fill=white]{+} (pro3)`

Comment: @marmot Till Tantau doesn't think it's that important, why do you think it's crucial?

Comment: My only request: Please consider stopping to propagate `\tikzstyle` further.

Comment: @marmot For what reason?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476253/tikz-get-values-for-predefined-dash-patterns-for-grid-in-the-option-help-lines#comment1202208_476253

Comment: @marmot I hope that the creators of TikZ will protect TikZ from the sacrilege of breaking with TikZ's backwards compatibility.