# How to get curved arrow originating and ending at the same node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Hi I'm trying to replicate the graph below. I've done most of it, but can't figure out a way to have an arrow originate and end at

[image: Aim to replicate this]

I've managed to get the below figure. And I'm stuck at produce the arrows on the Node E.

[image]

I've attached the code below

```
\tikzstyle{state} = [circle, minimum width=2cm, draw=black]
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, ->, >=stealth,auto, node distance=4cm]
    \node(shift) [state] {Shift $=1$};
    \node [above of=shift, yshift=-3.5cm] {S};
    \node(add) [state, right of=shift] {Add $=1$};
    \node [above of=add, yshift=-3.5cm] {A};
    \node(init) [state, right of=add] {Init $=1$};
    \node [above of=init, yshift=-3.5cm] {I};
    \node(control) [state, below of=add] {};
    \node [above of=control, yshift=-3.5cm] {C};
    \node(others) [state, below of=control] {};
    \node [above of=others, yshift=-3.5cm] {Others};
    \node(end) [state, right of=control] {Done $=1$};
    \node [above of=end, yshift=-3.5cm] {E};
    \node(reset) [circle, draw=black, fill=black, right of=end, xshift=-1.5cm] {};
    \node [above of=reset, yshift=-3.5cm] {Reset};

    \path (add) edge node [above] {$1$} (shift);
    \path (shift) edge[bend right] node [below left] {LSB/Stop $=00$} (control);
    \path (control) edge[] node [above right] {$1$} (shift);
    \path (control) edge[] node [right] {LSB $=1$} (add);
    \path (init) edge[] node [below right] {$1$} (control);
    \path (end) edge[] node [right] {Start $=1$} (init);
    \path (control) edge[] node [above] {$01$} (end);
    \path (others) edge[] node [above left] {$1$} (end);
    \path (reset) edge[] node [] {} (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this ? *(see commented line for explanations)*

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{state} = [circle, minimum width=2cm, draw=black]
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, ->, >=stealth,auto, node distance=4cm]
    \node(shift) [state] {Shift $=1$};
    \node [above of=shift, yshift=-3.5cm] {S};
    \node(add) [state, right of=shift] {Add $=1$};
    \node [above of=add, yshift=-3.5cm] {A};
    \node(init) [state, right of=add] {Init $=1$};
    \node [above of=init, yshift=-3.5cm] {I};
    \node(control) [state, below of=add] {};
    \node [above of=control, yshift=-3.5cm] {C};
    \node(others) [state, below of=control] {};
    \node [above of=others, yshift=-3.5cm] {Others};
    \node(end) [state, right of=control] {Done $=1$ };
    \draw (end) to [in=-40,out=220,looseness=5,min distance=30mm]node[above]{Start $=0$} (end);% <------ loop Start=0
    \node [above of=end, yshift=-3.5cm] {E };
    \node(reset) [circle, draw=black, fill=black, right of=end, xshift=-1.5cm] {};
    \node [above of=reset, yshift=-3.5cm] {Reset};

    \path (add) edge node [above] {$1$} (shift);
    \path (shift) edge[bend right] node [below left] {LSB/Stop $=00$} (control);
    \path (control) edge[] node [above right] {$1$} (shift);
    \path (control) edge[] node [right] {LSB $=1$} (add);
    \path (init) edge[] node [below right] {$1$} (control);
    \path (end) edge[] node [right] {Start $=1$} (init);
    \path (control) edge[] node [above] {$01$} (end);
    \path (others) edge[] node [above left] {$1$} (end.200);%<--- arrows a little above 
    \path (reset) edge[] node [] {} (end);
   %\node [circle,draw] at (end){} edge [in=30,out=60,loop] ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Addendum:

`\tikzstyle` is deprecated, use `\tikzset` instead, which give:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
%\tikzstyle{state} = [circle, minimum width=2cm, draw=black]
\tikzset{state/.style={circle, minimum width=2cm, draw=black}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, ->, >=stealth,auto, node distance=4cm]
    \node(shift) [state] {Shift $=1$};
    \node [above of=shift, yshift=-3.5cm] {S};
    \node(add) [state, right of=shift] {Add $=1$};
    \node [above of=add, yshift=-3.5cm] {A};
    \node(init) [state, right of=add] {Init $=1$};
    \node [above of=init, yshift=-3.5cm] {I};
    \node(control) [state, below of=add] {};
    \node [above of=control, yshift=-3.5cm] {C};
    \node(others) [state, below of=control] {};
    \node [above of=others, yshift=-3.5cm] {Others};
    \node(end) [state, right of=control] {Done $=1$ };
    \draw (end) to [in=-40,out=220,looseness=5,min distance=30mm]node[above]{Start $=0$} (end);% <------ loop Start=0
    \node [above of=end, yshift=-3.5cm] {E };
    \node(reset) [circle, draw=black, fill=black, right of=end, xshift=-1.5cm] {};
    \node [above of=reset, yshift=-3.5cm] {Reset};

    \path (add) edge node [above] {$1$} (shift);
    \path (shift) edge[bend right] node [below left] {LSB/Stop $=00$} (control);
    \path (control) edge[] node [above right] {$1$} (shift);
    \path (control) edge[] node [right] {LSB $=1$} (add);
    \path (init) edge[] node [below right] {$1$} (control);
    \path (end) edge[] node [right] {Start $=1$} (init);
    \path (control) edge[] node [above] {$01$} (end);
    \path (others) edge[] node [above left] {$1$} (end.200);%<--- arrows a little above 
    \path (reset) edge[] node [] {} (end);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476253/tikz-get-values-for-predefined-dash-patterns-for-grid-in-the-option-help-lines#comment1202208_476253