# How to put two colors in the same line/path in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, color

How can be colored a line/path in tikz?
i.e. green before the 5 and red after?
[image]

I have seen a option with

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
```

but this seems too much complex to the task (even though I couldn't do it).
But is the only way?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw[ blue] (-6,0)-- (9,0); 
    \foreach \x in {0,5} {
        \draw (\x,0.5) -- (\x,-0.5) node[below] {\x};
    }
    \draw[] (5,0) circle (0.5);
   
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321203/197451  -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488017/197451

Comment: You can always draw it as two separate lines, or if that is not convinient draw over the desired alternate color. Only the last color will show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `edge[]` is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \draw[ blue] (-6,0)-- +(0:11cm) edge[green] +(0:6cm) edge[red] (9,0); 
        \foreach \x in {0,5} {
            \draw (\x,0.5) -- (\x,-0.5) node[below] {\x};
        }
        \draw[] (5,0) circle (0.5);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how do you adjust the start/end of the color ?, +(0:11cm) edge[green]  means to start in (0,11) or from the value of 0 to the 11 over x?

Comment: Here you will find a good explanation what [edge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314301/tikz-when-will-i-need-to-use-edge-and-how-does-it-differ-from-the-conventional) does.