# Curve solid then dotted in picture

Tags: picture-mode

I want to draw a curve which is solid over `$0$` to `$\rho_1$`, but dashed (or dotted) thereafter.
But, despite much experimentation, I can only get it solid all the time.  Any thoughts appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,font=12]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,spy,positioning,snakes}
\usepackage{curves}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\unitlength = 1mm
\begin{picture}(70,70)(0,0)
\put(0,0){\vector(1,0){70}}
\put(0,0){\vector(0,1){70}}
  \put(25,0){\circle*{1.7}}
    \put(25,-4){${\rho}_1$}
\put(-10,50){$m(0)$}
{ \curve(0,50, 25, 35, 50, 0) }
\end{picture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45275/tikz-get-values-for-predefined-dash-patterns/45276

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is i want to have a curve which is part solid, part dashed. This link (though certainly helpful) doesn't seem to address that possibility if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You load TikZ but then use picture for your drawing.  Are you interested in other drawing methods, such as TikZ, or does it have to be using the picture environment?

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to try `lualatex`, then you could use [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    numeric u; u = 1mm;
    path xx, yy, ff;

    xx = origin -- (70u, 0);
    yy = xx rotated 90;
    ff = ((0, 50) .. (25, 35) .. (50, 0)) scaled u;
    
    draw subpath (0, 1) of ff withcolor 2/3 blue;
    draw subpath (1, 2) of ff dashed withdots scaled 1/2 withcolor 2/3 blue;

    drawarrow xx;
    drawarrow yy;

    dotlabel.lft("$m(0)$", point 0 of ff);
    dotlabel.bot("$\rho_1$", (xpart point 1 of ff, 0));

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex`...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an Asymptote solution for comparison. [Here](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) the functions `times` and `subpath`.

```
real[] times(path p, real x)
```

returns all intersection times of path `p` with the vertical line through `(x,0)`;

```
path subpath(path p, real a, real b);
```

returns the subpath of `p` running from path time `a` to path time `b`, in the sense of `point(path, real)`. If `a > b`, the direction of the subpath is reversed.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(8mm);
real a=2;
path m=(0, 5) .. (2.5, 3.5) .. (5,0);
real[] t=times(m,a);
pair A=(a,0);
pair M=point(m,t[0]);
path m1=subpath(m,0,t[0]);
path m2=subpath(m,t[0],length(m));
draw(A--M,gray);
draw(m1,blue);
draw(m2,red+dashed);
dot(M,red);
dot("$a$",align=S,A);
dot(scale(.6)*"$m(0)$",align=W,point(m,0));
import graph;
axes("$x$","$y$",min=(-.5,-.5),max=(6,6),Arrow(TeXHead));
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought to come up with a TikZ solution (as it's been a while since this was posted and there are now two non-picture solutions), but to do that I had to figure out what `\curve` was doing and that led me to the `curves` package which you are loading.  In reading that, I discovered the `\tagcurve` command which omits the first and last segments of a `\curve`, so that they are used to *define* the curve but not render it.  When applied to a `\curve` with only three defining points, it omits only the last segment.  Since your curve only has three defining points this suggests a cunning strategy: use `\tagcurve` twice - once with the points in reverse - to draw each segment of your curve separately.

Now it may be that in your question you use a very simple example and that your real use-case has a much more complicated curve.  But actually, this could be extended if you use `\tagcurve` instead of `\curve` throughout since the purpose of `\tagcurve` is to draw each segment *as if* it were part of a larger curve.  So splitting a `\tagcurve` into shorter segments (with suitable repetition of the vertices either side of the break) should just produce a shorter segment *of exactly the same curve*.

So here's a picture version of what you're asking for.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/576435/86}
\usepackage{curves}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\unitlength = 1mm
\begin{picture}(70,70)(0,0)
\put(0,0){\vector(1,0){70}}
\put(0,0){\vector(0,1){70}}
  \put(25,0){\circle*{1.7}}
    \put(25,-4){${\rho}_1$}
\put(-10,50){$m(0)$}
{
  \curvedashes[1mm]{0.5,1.5}
  \tagcurve(0,50, 25, 35, 50, 0) }
{ \tagcurve(50,0, 25, 35, 0,50) }
\end{picture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: A curve that becomes dashed half way along]

Notes:

1. This works because the point at which you want to switch behaviour (above rho) is one of your specified vertices along the curve.
2. I would actually do this with TikZ.  You are loading TikZ anyway, so the general argument for using the picture environment as a smaller footprint is spurious.  And even if you were not, the flexibility from using a more powerful drawing package - whether TikZ or asymptote or pstricks - vastly outweighs that.