# Drawing a long dashed line

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, line

In this link [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45275/tikz-get-values-for-predefined-dash-patterns) there are several styles of dashed lines. But none of them shows a long dashed format. How can I draw a long dashed line, for example, by a newcommand or TikZ? (A picture the same as below one.)

[image]

I mean an arbitrary size for any slice and arbitrary space between them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, even with many lengths in a pattern:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [very thick,dash pattern={on 10pt off 2pt on 5pt off 2pt}] (0,0) -- (6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]