# Dotted lines in TikZ with round dots

Tags: tikz-pgf

Well, the title explains all, I guess. Sorry if this is too simple for all the TikZ gurus here: but I want a dash pattern like "dotted" for drawning but with round dots and not the little squares. How can I achieve this in a simple way?

Comment: You could maybe achieve this with one of the decorations library?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could define a custom dash pattern with an `on` length of `0pt`. If you set `line cap=round`, you'll end up with perfect circles. The `dash pattern` approach is much faster than using `decorations` for the same purpose.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=3pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 2\pgflinewidth] (0,0) -- (3,0) to [out=0, in=0, looseness=2] (3,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

The whole thing can of course be made into a new style so you just have to use `dots`, and which allows you to comfortably set the dot diameter using `dot diameter` and the dot spacing using `dot spacing`

```
\draw [dots] ...
```

[image]

```
\draw [red, dot diameter=5pt, dot spacing=5pt, dots] ...
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    dot diameter/.store in=\dot@diameter,
    dot diameter=3pt,
    dot spacing/.store in=\dot@spacing,
    dot spacing=10pt,
    dots/.style={
        line width=\dot@diameter,
        line cap=round,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off \dot@spacing
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dots] (0,0) -- (3,0) to [out=0, in=0, looseness=2] (3,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red, dot diameter=5pt, dot spacing=5pt, dots] (0,0) -- (3,0) to [out=0, in=0, looseness=2] (3,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Works perfect. I'm just playing a bit with the parameters to get what I need :)

Answer (score 17):

Another possibility is to exploit the `decorations` libraries as Lionel suggested: one example presented will be based on `decorations.markings` while the other one on `decorations.shapes`.

> **Decorations.markings**

The code:

```
\documentclass[png,tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  circle color/.initial=black,
  circle color/.get=\circlecolor,
  circle color/.store in=\circlecolor,
}

\tikzset{dotted pattern/.style args={#1 and #2}{
   postaction=decorate,
   decoration={
    markings,
    mark=
    between positions 0 and 1 step #2
      with
      {
       \fill[radius=#1,\circlecolor] (0,0) circle;
      }
    }
  },
  dotted pattern/.default={1pt and 1.5mm},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [dotted pattern] 
  (0,0) -- (3,0) to [out=0, in=0, looseness=2] (3,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [circle color=red,
   dotted pattern=1.5pt and 4mm] 
  (0,0) -- (3,0) to [out=0, in=0, looseness=2] (3,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

provides:

[image]

and

[image]

Indeed, with the `dotted pattern` style you can customize the radius and the distance between the circles respectively while with the `circle color` key you may change the color.

> **Decorations.shapes**

The code:

```
\documentclass[png,tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  circle color/.initial=black,
  circle color/.get=\circlecolor,
  circle color/.store in=\circlecolor,
}

\tikzset{dotted pattern/.style args={#1 and #2}{
   decorate,
   fill=\circlecolor,
   decoration={
    shape backgrounds,
    shape=circle,
    shape size=#1,
    shape sep={#2, between center}, 
    }
  },
  dotted pattern/.default={1pt and 1.5mm},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [dotted pattern] 
  (0,0) -- (3,0) to [out=0, in=0, looseness=2] (3,-1); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [circle color=red,
   dotted pattern=1.5pt and 4mm] 
  (0,0) -- (3,0) to [out=0, in=0, looseness=2] (3,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result are still the pictures shown above. In order to use `\draw` rather than `\path`, one might add a `draw=none` to the `dotted pattern` style.

Comment: Note that this approach is orders of magnitudes slower than using `dash pattern`: Compiling a document containing only a `tikzpicture` with `\draw [dot diameter=2pt, dot spacing=4pt, dots] (0,0) grid (10,10);` takes about 0.13 seconds on my system, but `\path [dotted pattern=1pt and 4pt] (0,0) grid (10,10);` takes more than 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, it's true (made a test and I got something near 9 seconds to be honest): and it suffers also when the space between two consecutive dots is high (as per the second example).

Comment: @Claudio. Thanks also to you. Compilation time might really be an issue, so I think I will stick to the solution of Jake. But anyway: amazing what one can do with TikZ. Thanks again!

Comment: @StefanWaldmann: the answer was more intended as _another way to do it_; moreover, as all efficiency-related issues, the compilation time is mainly based on _what_ you're doing: if the purpose is to use a simple path, then Jake's approach and mine are comparable. For complicated and heavy things, like the `grid`, this is not more true.

Comment: **NOTICE**: the `decorations.shapes` is even slower than `decorations.markings` (in order to compile the grid I had to use LuaLaTeX). @Jake: I was wondering, just for `decorations.markings`, if adding a `reset marks` will be of help...

Comment: Does anyone know why the compilation is so slow? Up to 9 seconds for such a small picture is really limiting the usefulness.