# Plotting loops: trajectories and directions

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, loops

Plotting loops: trajectories have directions.
How to plot the following figures using tikz

[image]

1st I start to plot the 2nd fig using the code

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (3,2) ellipse (.5cm and .25cm);
\draw (2.9,1.9) to [controls=+(90:1) and +(90:1)] (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

To plot the last fig, I have used.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  (.5,0) .. controls (3,3) and (-1,3) .. (1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But unable to plt the outer and inside curves and the arrows.
Using Hobby I wrote

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
 \draw  (-.3 ,1).. (0, 0) .. ( 1.2 , 0 ) .. ( 0 , 0 ) .. (-.3 ,-1);
 \draw  (.45, 0) .. ( .9 , 0 ) .. ( .6 , 0 ) .. ( .7 , -0.01);
\draw  (-.15, 1.2).. (-.01, .2) ..(.01, .22).. (.6, .1) .. ( 1.3 , 0 ) .. ( 0 , -.1 ) .. (-.3 ,-1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But problem for the outer curve persists. What to do?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  use Hobby shortcut,
  vec1/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,      % v-- can fine-tune arrow position and rotation
      mark=at position 0.1 with {\arrow[rotate=5]{stealth}},
    }
  },
  vec2/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,      % v-- here again---fine-tune as needed
      mark=at position 0.080 with {\arrow{stealth}},
      mark=at position 0.206 with {\arrow{stealth reversed}},
      mark=at position 0.800 with {\arrow{stealth reversed}},
      mark=at position 0.930 with {\arrow{stealth}},
    }
  },
]
  % filled points
  %\fill (0,0) circle (1pt);
  %\fill (2,0) circle (1pt);
     \draw (0.4, 0) .. (0.8, 0.3) .. (1.0, 0) .. (0.4, 0);
    \draw  (-.3 ,1).. (0, 0) .. ( 1.2 , 0 )
     \draw  (-.3 ,-1).. (0, 0) .. ( 1.2 , 0 ) .. ( 0 , 0 ) ;
     \draw   (.5, 0) .. ( .8 , 0 ) .. ( .6 , 0 ) .. ( .7 , -0.012);
     \draw (-.1, 1)..(-.08, .7)..(-.05, .4)..( .1 , .4 )..( .7 , .6 )..( 1.4 , 0 )..( .7 , -.6 )..( .2 , -.4 )..(-.1,-.5)..(-.11 ,-.8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? What problems do you have?

Comment: I would use [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) for this and the library `decorations.markings` for the arrows: see [How to draw two opposite arrows on the same curve?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155350/13304)

Comment: @user1942348: it is plenty of examples in this site: [just browse hobby](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=hobby).

Comment: I have tried. Would you please help me to draw any one of the figures at your earliest?

Comment: Your example does not compile... you are missing a semicolon after your added `\draw` command.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. But I am not getting the nice pic that you have done.

Comment: You just have to adjust the points in the curve until you achieve what you want. Try to make the curves bit by bit so you see what `hobby` is doing. As Claudio recommended, search for other `hobby` examples to get a feel for how the algorithm works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution using `hobby` for the third image. This should be enough to get you started on the other two.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  use Hobby shortcut,
  vec1/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,      % v-- can fine-tune arrow position and rotation
      mark=at position 0.1 with {\arrow[rotate=5]{stealth}},
    }
  },
  vec2/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,      % v-- here again---fine-tune as needed
      mark=at position 0.080 with {\arrow{stealth}},
      mark=at position 0.206 with {\arrow{stealth reversed}},
      mark=at position 0.800 with {\arrow{stealth reversed}},
      mark=at position 0.930 with {\arrow{stealth}},
    }
  },
]
  % filled points
  \fill (0,0) circle (1pt);
  \fill (2,0) circle (1pt);

  % inner loop
  \draw[postaction=vec1] (-0.6,0.1) .. (0,0.4) .. (0.4,0) .. 
    (0,-0.4) .. (-0.25,-0.25) .. (-0.1,0.1);

  % middle crossing loop
  \draw[postaction=vec2] (3,-1) .. (2,0) .. (0,0.93) .. 
    (-0.93,0) .. (0,-0.93) .. (2,0) .. (3,1);

  % outer loop
  \draw[-stealth] (2.75,-1) .. (2,-0.75) .. (1.25,-1) .. (0,-1.25) .. 
    (-1.25,0) .. (0,1.25) .. (1.25,1) .. (2,0.75) .. (2.75,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: May I get code to draw the 2nd fig. I would be very happy, if you would be kind enough to send me the associate code.

Comment: @user1942348 what specific problems are you having? It should be fairly straightforward to modify my code to produce the second image. Also, a suggestion: Please do us a favor and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: I am very much thankful of getting your help for the last figure. The specific problem is that I am unable to bend the curves smoothly as you have done. I would earnestly request you to draw the 2nd figure for me and hope that after that comparing the two, I will be able to draw other fig. SO, please favor me for the 2nd fig.

Comment: @Paul_Gessler (Paul Gessler) Please help me this time at your earliest convenience. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1942348 show us (edit the question) what you've tried so far and people will be more than happy to help.