# Elegant way to put marks that are not equidistant along path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put circles along path, but they are not equidistant.  The problem is that code is repetitive and ugly.  Is there any other more elegant way to do that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[decoration={markings,%
  mark=at position 0.1 with {\fill (0,0) circle (0.06);},%
  mark=at position 0.35 with {\fill (0,0) circle (0.06);},%
  mark=at position 0.5 with {\fill (0,0) circle (0.06);},%
  mark=at position 0.7 with {\fill (0,0) circle (0.06);},%
  mark=at position 0.85 with {\fill (0,0) circle (0.06);}},%
  postaction={decorate}] (0,0) arc (-35:-30:15) arc (-30:35:2) arc (215:170:1.5) arc (170:165:15);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is why it exists the option `between positions x and y step z`: see [How to make a figure with moving arrows?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121910/13304)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I think `between positions x and y step z` produces equidistant decorations.

Comment: @Ignasi: right.. my comment comes after having read the first sentence, where it seemed to me that the OP exactly wanted equidistant circles

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `/.list` instead with a custom style that uses markings a few times. Otherwise you have to hack a macro that is not so fun.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/decoration/irregular markings/.style = {
    mark= at position#1with {\fill (0,0) circle (0.06);}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[decoration={markings,irregular markings/.list={0.1,0.35,0.5,0.7,0.85}},
      postaction={decorate}
] (0,0) arc (-35:-30:15) arc (-30:35:2) arc (215:170:1.5) arc (170:165:15);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]