# How to draw a graph of a specific form in LaTeX

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

[image]

How can I draw a graph like this in LaTeX using pgfplot package?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried anything? If so, can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: So far, I have been trying the usual one  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines = left,
      xlabel = $Tails(x)$,
      ylabel = $Heads(y)$,
  ]

  \addplot [
     domain=0:15, 
      samples=15, 
      ]
  {- x + 10};
  \addlegendentry{$x+y=n$}     Thank you

Comment: I think you might find useful [How to make a figure with moving arrows?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121910/13304)

Comment: God! I can not even right the code!!

Comment: Yes, I think that can solve my problem. @ClaudioFiandrino

Comment: You can edit your questions, and for code it's much better if you add it to the question itself, rather than in comments. For syntax highlighting, select the code and hit Ctrl + K (or click the button marked `{}` above the text field).

Comment: @Ragnar: Excellent. Please feel free to post the code of the solution as answer :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Let me try to edit and run the code :)

Answer (score 3):

I have edited a little bit on the code given by @Claudio. and I came up with this solution. [image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[->, thick](0,0)--node[below]{$Tails(x)$}(5,0) ;
    \draw[->, thick](0,0)--node[left]{$Heads(y)$}(0,5);
    \draw[- ] (4,0)node[below]{$(n,0)$}--(0,4) node[right] {$(0,n)$};


    \node[right] at (3.6,0.4) {$(n-1,1)$};
    \node[right] at (0.4,3.6) {$(1,n-1)$};
    \node[right] at (0.8,3.2) {$(2,n-2)$};
    \node[right] at (3,3) {$\mathbf{x+y=n}$};

    \fill (0,4) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (4,0) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (3.6,0.4) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (0.4,3.6) circle (1.5pt);
    \fill (0.8,3.2) circle (1.5pt);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}` and then `$\text{Tails}(x)$`, `$\text{Heads}(y)$`.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning   \usepackage{amsmath}    but the other two are done in a different way, as repositioned nodes. @TorbjørnT.

Comment: My main point was that you don't want to write `Tails` and `Heads` in math mode, they are words, not a string of variables. I only mentioned `amsmath` because it defines `\text`.

Comment: Alright, but '\mathbf' is also from 'amsmath ' package, if I am not wrong.

Comment: No, you don't need `amsmath` to use `\mathbf` (which your example proves, it works without `amsmath`). Don't think `amsmath` defines any font styles at all actually, but for `\mathbb` for example you need `amsfonts`.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment is almost a solution.  You might want to use `axis lines=middle` to match the sketch from your question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$\mathrm{Tails}(x)$,
    ylabel=$\mathrm{Heads}(y)$,
    domain=0:15,no marks]
    \addplot {-x + 10};
    \addlegendentry{$x+y=n$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]