# How to label a TiKz shape for referencing its legend in the caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend

How can I label a TiKz line style for further referencing in figure caption.
For `\addplot` the label just follows it. However, I don't know how to do it for `\draw`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\tikzset{pointille/.style={dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt on 6pt off 2pt}}
\tikzset{points/.style={dash pattern = on 1pt off 1pt}}
\tikzset{tirets/.style={dash pattern = on 5pt off 5pt}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\captionsetup{width=9.5cm}
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none,line width=1.5pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=7cm,width=9cm,grid=major,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$f(x)$,
tick label style={font=\footnotesize},label style={font=\small},max space between ticks=45, major tick length=0cm,minor tick length=0cm,enlargelimits=false,]
\addplot[tirets,color=blue]{2*x};\label{p4}
\addplot[pointille,color=green]{0.5*x*x};\label{p5}
\addplot[points,color=red]{-0.125*x*x*x};\label{p6}
\end{axis}

\draw [dashed,red,thick] (1,1) rectangle (2,2); \label{p7}
\draw [solid,blue,thick] (1,1)-- (2,2); \label{p8}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Caption in ToC]{This is a plot about colored curves: $f(x)=2 x$ (\ref{p4}),  $f(x)=0.5 x^2$ (\ref{p5}), and $f(x)=-0.125 x^3$ (\ref{p6}), (\ref{p7}), and (\ref{p8})}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: If you want circles instead of rectangles for your `points` style, you can set `\tikzset{points/.style={line cap=round, dash pattern = on 0pt off 3pt}}` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101263/2552)

Answer (score 4):

That `\label`/`\ref` functionality is provided by PGFPlots (not TikZ), and only works for plots, not arbitrary `\draw` commands.

You could achieve the desired result by using an `\addplot` command for drawing the objects: You can replace `\draw [dashed,red,thick] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);` with `\addplot [dashed,red,thick] coordinates {(1,1)} rectangle (2,2);`. You only need to provide the first coordinate of your path in the `coordinates` list, after that you can use normal TikZ path commands like `rectangle` or `--`. Note that the coordinate system is scaled inside the `axis` environment, so your best bet is to work with `(axis cs:<x>,<y>)` coordinates instead of trying to find the right values using "normal" coordinates.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\tikzset{pointille/.style={dash pattern = on 2pt off 2pt on 6pt off 2pt}}
\tikzset{points/.style={dash pattern = on 1pt off 1pt}}
\tikzset{tirets/.style={dash pattern = on 5pt off 5pt}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\captionsetup{width=9.5cm}
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none,line width=1.5pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=7cm,width=9cm,grid=major,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$f(x)$,
tick label style={font=\footnotesize},label style={font=\small},max space between ticks=45, major tick length=0cm,minor tick length=0cm,enlargelimits=false,]
\addplot[tirets,color=blue]{2*x};\label{p4}
\addplot[pointille,color=green]{0.5*x*x};\label{p5}
\addplot[points,color=red]{-0.125*x*x*x};\label{p6}
\addplot [dashed,red,thick] coordinates {(-4,-10)} rectangle (axis cs:-2,-3); \label{p7}
\addplot [solid,blue,thick] coordinates {(-4, -10)} -- (axis cs:-2,-3); \label{p8}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Caption in ToC]{This is a plot about colored curves: $f(x)=2 x$ (\ref{p4}),  $f(x)=0.5 x^2$ (\ref{p5}), and $f(x)=-0.125 x^3$ (\ref{p6}), (\ref{p7}), and (\ref{p8})}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake, I have no idea why this doesn't work for `PGFplots` while I could use it for `\draw`:
`\addplot [red,thick,dashed,forget plot] coordinates {({axis cs:1.0,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1})} -- ({axis cs:1.0,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0.0});\label{vertline}`

Comment: @M.Reza: The coordinates provided in `\addplot coordinates {...}` must be a simple list of coordinates: No `axis cs` (they're already in the axis coordinate system), no path commands. You only need (and should) provide the first coordinate in that list, so you could say `\addplot [red,thick,dashed,forget plot] coordinates {(1,1)} -- ({axis cs:1.0,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0.0})`. That coordinate expression is a bit weird, though: Why are you using the orthogonal (`|-`) expression here? `(1,0|-0,1)` is equivalent to `(1,1)`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to plot a vertical line on a plot by using:
`\draw [color=red,thick,dashed]({axis cs:1.0,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) -- ({axis cs:1.0,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0.0}); \end{axis}`. The reason I chose this is that, I can use the axis coordinates the first part `{axis cs:1.0,0}` (like specific point on x axis), but I don't need to calculate the y coordinates for the second part `|-{rel axis cs:0,1})` as `rel axis cs:0,1` places the point at the top of the plot regardless of y coordinates. I am not sure though if I'm using it correctly!

Comment: @M.Reza: Ah, oops, I missed the `rel` bit. Yeah, that makes sense. In that case, I would use `\makeatletter
\addplot [red,thick,dashed,forget plot] coordinates {(\pgfplots@data@xmin,\pgfplots@data@ymin)} ({axis cs:1.0,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,1}) --  ({axis cs:1.0,0}|-{rel axis cs:0,0.0});`. That way, the coordinate supplied in `\addplot coordinates {...}` doesn't impact the axis limits.