# Draw dotted line with circled dots and automatic spacing

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm trying to create dotted lines with [tikz](/questions/tagged/tikz) where every dot has a defined size and a circle around it, with also a defined size.

First I applied [**this answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101263/36835) to create a dash pattern:

```
\tikzset{
    dot diameter/.store in=\dot@diameter,
    dot diameter=3pt,
    dot spacing/.store in=\dot@spacing,
    dot spacing=10pt,
    dots/.style={
        line width=\dot@diameter,
        line cap=round,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off \dot@spacing
    }
}
```

Then I plot these dotted lines in **black - white - black** on top of each other to achieve the desired effect. **How can I change the tikzset to get this in one step?**

The next problem is that it requires a defined **dot-spacing** which is fine if I'd knew the distance between the endpoints of my line, which I usually don't, so I'm fiddling around with the spacing manually. But I'd like to have a circled dot at the beginning and end node and the rest of the dots equally spaced inbetween. **How can I achieve that equal distribution?** Is it possible to define, say, **exactly 11 dots** on that line, equally distributed?

Thank you!

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    dot diameter/.store in=\dot@diameter,
    dot diameter=3pt,
    dot spacing/.store in=\dot@spacing,
    dot spacing=10pt,
    dots/.style={
        line width=\dot@diameter,
        line cap=round,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off \dot@spacing
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (A1) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B1) at (5,1);
    \coordinate (A2) at (1,1.5);
    \coordinate (B2) at (5,1.5);

    % for reference frame
    \draw [black, thick]   (A1.center) -- (B1.center) -- (B2.center) -- (A2.center) -- (A1.center);

    % three dot layers #1
    \draw [black, dot diameter=3mm, dot spacing=3.8mm, dots]   (A1.center) -- (B1.center);
    \draw [white, dot diameter=2.5mm, dot spacing=3.8mm, dots]  (A1.center) -- (B1.center);
    \draw [black, dot diameter=1mm, dot spacing=3.8mm, dots]    (A1.center) -- (B1.center);

    % three dot layers #2
    \draw [black, dot diameter=3mm, dot spacing=4mm, dots]   (A2.center) -- (B2.center);
    \draw [white, dot diameter=2.5mm, dot spacing=4mm, dots]  (A2.center) -- (B2.center);
    \draw [black, dot diameter=1mm, dot spacing=4mm, dots]    (A2.center) -- (B2.center);


    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The solid line is just for orientation, there shouldn't be a connect between the dots. The upper dotted line is manually adjusted to get the correct spacing.

Answer (score 3):

This answer proposes to use `preaction` and|or `postaction` to define a style which draws all three layers in one command but doesn't solve the problem about equally distributed 11 dots between two points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    dot diameter/.store in=\dot@diameter,
    dot diameter=3pt,
    dot spacing/.store in=\dot@spacing,
    dot spacing=10pt,
    dots/.style={
        line width=\dot@diameter,
        line cap=round,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off \dot@spacing
    },
     mydots/.style={
        dot spacing=3.8mm,
        preaction={draw=black,
                        dot diameter=3mm,
                        dots},
        draw = white,
        dot diameter=2.5mm,
        dots,
        postaction={draw=black,
                        dot diameter=1mm,
                        dots},
     }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw [mydots]   (0,0) -- (4,0);

    \draw [mydots]   (0,1) .. controls (3,1) and (4,2).. (3,3);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** Parametric version: `\mydots={dot dimension}{distance}`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    dot diameter/.store in=\dot@diameter,
    dot diameter=3pt,
    dot spacing/.store in=\dot@spacing,
    dot spacing=10pt,
    dots/.style={
        line width=#1,
        line cap=round,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off \dot@spacing
    },
     mydots/.style 2 args={
        dot spacing=#2,
        preaction={draw=black,
                        dots=#1},
        draw = white,
        dots=.8*#1,
        postaction={draw=black,
                        dots=.333*#1},
     }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw [mydots={3mm}{3.8mm}]   (0,0) -- (4,0);

    \draw [mydots={2mm}{5mm}]   (0,1) .. controls (3,1) and (4,2).. (3,3);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But it seems that I can just predefine the dot diameters of pre- and post-action, right? The creating of the variable `dot innerdiameter/.store in=\dot@innerdiameter,` and use it with pre- and post-action does not seem to work. Also `preaction={draw=black,
                        dot diameter=\dot@diameter,
                        dots},` does not work. Somehow the size of the dots must be controllable, either relative to each other by specifying just one of the dot sizes or all three absolute.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. In any case I've updated the answer with a parametric `dots` style. Is something like this what you want?

Comment: you haven't updated the answer like mentioned in you comment as there is no edit, have you?

Comment: @thewaywewalk: Sorry, I did it, but probably forgot to click save button. Now it's ok.

Comment: This works great. But the automatic sapcing is not trivial to realize, is it?