# How to draw a tangent line to the following curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

I want to draw the following diagram
[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xtick = \empty,    ytick = \empty,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            x label style = {at={(1,0)},anchor=west},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            y label style = {at={(0,1)},rotate=-90,anchor=south},
            axis lines=center,
            enlargelimits=0.2,
        ]
        \addplot[color=red,smooth,thick,-] {(x)^2};
        \addplot[color=blue,mark=*,label={right:$P$}] (2,4);
        \addplot[mark=none, blue] coordinates {(-1,-2) (3,6)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The tangent to `x^2` trhough `(2,4)` is `y=4x-4`.

Comment: question seems to be calculus problem :-)

Comment: Maybe [how to graph general functions in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394604/124842) could help (with x^2). - Related: [How to draw tangent line of an arbitrary point on a path in TikZ(https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25940/124842)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun: `pstricks-add` has a `\psplotTangent` command which accepts three arguments: the abscissa of the point of contact, the length of both sides of the tangent segment and the function:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, x11names, border = 5pt]{standalone}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}%,
\usepackage{pst-eucl, auto-pst-pdf}%

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=2.2cm, yunit = 2cm, arrowinset = 0.12, algebraic, plotstyle = curve, plotpoints = 100}

\begin{pspicture*}(-2,-1.2)(3,3)
\psplot{-2}{2.7}{x^2}
\uput[l](-1,1){$y = x^2$}
\pstGeonode[PosAngle = {0,180}, PointName=](1,1){P}(1.6,2.56){Q}
\uput[r](P){$P(1,1)$}\uput[l](Q){$Q(x, x^2)$}
\pstLineAB[linecolor = LightSteelBlue, nodesep = -5, showpoints]{P}{Q}
\psplotTangent[linecolor = SkyBlue, showpoints]{1}{2.5}{x^2}
\psaxes[linewidth = 0.6pt, labels = none, ticks = none, arrows = ->](0,0)(-2,-1.2)(3,3)[$x$, -110][$y$,210]
\uput[dl](0,0){$0$}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Of course, it's better to have 
a functional expression for the tangent line,
which in this example is a simple exercise.
However, `Asymptote` offers a "calculus-free" way
of drawing the tangent lines. 
There is 
a built-in function `dir(path, time)`
exactly for this purpose.

Let's pretend, that we don't know 
how to obtain the tangent line equation for the function.

Given the function curve `guide gf` and `x=1`, 
we can use built-in function `times`

```
t=times(gf,x)[0];
```

to get a value of the time parameter `t`, which corresponds
to the intersection of the function curve and a vertical line at `x=1`.
This `t` value allows to: first, 
get a missing 'y' coordinate of the tangent point `P`

```
P=point(gf,t);
```

And second, the direction of the tangent line at this point
as `dir(gf,t)`.

Function `drawline` 
(part of the basic `Asymptote` module `math.asy`),
allows to draw the visible portion 
of the (infinite) line 
going through two points:

```
drawline(P,P+dir(gf,t),tanLinePen);
```

Another useful function for this drawing 
is `relpoint`, which
returns the point on curve 
at the relative fraction of its arclength.

This is a complete `MWE`:

```
// tan.asy
//
// run 
// asy tan.asy
//
// to get tan.pdf
//
settings.tex="pdflatex";
import graph; import math;
size(6cm);
import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}"
+"\usepackage{amsmath}"
+"\usepackage{amsfonts}"
+"\usepackage{amssymb}"
);
pen funcLinePen=darkblue+0.9bp;
pen tanLinePen=orange+0.9bp;
pen grayPen=gray(0.3)+0.8bp;
pen dashPen=gray(0.3)+0.8bp+linetype(new real[]{5,5})+linecap(0);
arrowbar arr=Arrow(HookHead,size=2);
real xmin=-2,xmax=-xmin;
real ymin=0,ymax=4;
real dxmin=0.2;
real dxmax=dxmin;
real dymin=dxmin;
real dymax=dxmax;

add(shift(-2.5,-1)*scale(0.5)*grid(10,11,paleblue+0.3bp));

xaxis("$x$",xmin-dxmin,xmax+dxmax,RightTicks(Step=1,step=0.5),arr,above=true);
yaxis("$y$",ymin-dymin,ymax+dymax,LeftTicks (Step=1,step=0.5,OmitTick(0)),arr,above=true);

real f(real x){return x^2;}

guide gf=graph(f,xmin,xmax,operator..);

real x=1, t=times(gf,x)[0];
pair P=point(gf,t), Q=relpoint(gf,6/7);

draw(gf,funcLinePen);
draw((P.x,0)--P--(0,P.y),dashPen);
drawline(P,P+dir(gf,t),tanLinePen);
dot((P.x,0)^^P^^(0,P.y)^^Q,UnFill);
label("$y=x^2$",relpoint(gf,1/4),UnFill);
label("$P(1,"+string(round(P.y))+")$",P,plain.SE);
label("$Q(x,x^2)$",Q,plain.W);
label("$T$",Q,3*plain.E);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised that the original question is tagged [tikz-pgf](/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) but one answer (the accepted one) uses [pstricks](/questions/tagged/pstricks) and the other uses [asymptote](/questions/tagged/asymptote)! So I decide to post a Ti*k*Z answer, but this is mainly a mathematics answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=\x*\x;}]
\draw[-latex] (-2.5,0)--(2.5,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-2)--(0,2.5) node[left] {$y$};
\draw plot[smooth,samples=100,domain=-1.5:1.5] (\x,{f(\x)});
\path (0,0) node[below left] {$0$};
\fill (1,{f(1)}) coordinate (p) circle (1pt);
\coordinate (x) at (0,{1/(4*f(1))});
\node[circle through={(p)}] (cir) at (x) {};
\draw[shorten >=-1.5cm,shorten <=-1cm] (cir.south)--(p);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This code works for any *P* on the parabola once the equation of the parabola is still in the form of *ax*<sup>2</sup>. For general case *ax*<sup>2</sup> + *bx* + *c*, please edit the coordinate of (*x*)!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=2*\x*\x;}]
\draw[-latex] (-2.5,0)--(2.5,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-2)--(0,2.5) node[left] {$y$};
\draw plot[smooth,samples=100,domain=-1.5:1.5] (\x,{f(\x)});
\path (0,0) node[below left] {$0$};
\fill (-.5,{f(-.5)}) coordinate (p) circle (1pt);
\coordinate (x) at (0,{1/(4*f(1))});
\node[circle through={(p)}] (cir) at (x) {};
\draw[shorten >=-1.5cm,shorten <=-1cm] (cir.south)--(p);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### Proof of correctness

I find the focus of the parabola, after that I can find another point on the tangent line.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=\x*\x;}]
\draw[-latex] (-2.5,0)--(2.5,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-2)--(0,2.5) node[left] {$y$};
\draw plot[smooth,samples=100,domain=-1.5:1.5] (\x,{f(\x)});
\path (0,0) node[below left] {$0$};
\fill (1.2,{f(1.2)}) coordinate (p) circle (1pt);
\coordinate (x) at (0,{1/(4*f(1))});
\fill (x) circle (1pt);
\node[draw,very thin,dashed,circle through={(p)}] (cir) at (x) {};
\fill (cir.south) circle (1pt);
\draw[shorten >=-1.5cm,shorten <=-1cm] (cir.south)--(p);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,font=\scriptsize]
\tzaxes*(-2,-1.2)(2,2.3){$x$}{$y$}
\tzshoworigin
\def\Fx{(\x)^2}
\settztangentlayer{main}
\settzsecantlayer{main}
\clip (-2,-1.2) rectangle (2.3,2.3);
\tzfn\Fx[-1.5:1.5]
\tzvXpointat*{Fx}{1}(A){$P(1,1)$}[0](1pt)
\tzvXpointat*{Fx}{1.4}(B){$Q(x,x^2)$}[180](1pt)
\tztangent[cyan,opacity=.7]{Fx}(A)[-.2:1.7]{$T$}[br]
\tzsecant[green,opacity=.7]{Fx}(A)(B)[.1:2]
\tzvXpointat{Fx}{-1}{$y=x^2$}[bl]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```