# How can I graph these figures from scratch?

Tags: diagrams

Good Morning. At the moment I am new in the topic of creating graphics in latex. I know how to handle the editor on average, but I'm just getting started on this topic. I would like you to guide me on how to create graphs of this type and if they have information material that could help me, it would be very useful. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: search this site with the terms curve and plot   You will find lots of good examples.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!THis could be useful: [How to draw general functions and tangent lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394368/124842)

Comment: The PGF/Ti*k*Z sample site also has lots of examples. The manual for the drawing package you prefer will probably do so, too. Ti*k*Z, `pstricks` and `pgfplots` are popular.

Comment: Muchas gracias.