# pgfplots - dotted line style - why square dots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When using `dotted` line style in a `pgfplot`, I realised that the dots are really square dots.

[image]

Usually most people associate dot with a filled circle(or is it just me?). And I know that there are [workarounds](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101262/dotted-lines-in-tikz-with-round-dots) to get the 'real dotted' line style.
I am curious to know why `pgfplot` associates dot with a square dot, by default, in line style.

Here is source for the above figure:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel= $x$,
  ylabel= $y$,
  ymax = 6,
  legend columns=-1,
         ]
\addplot[mark=none, black, dotted] coordinates {(0,2) (5,2)};
\addplot[mark=none, black,thick, dotted] coordinates {(0,3) (5,3)};
\addplot[mark=none, black, very thick,dotted] coordinates {(0,4) (5,4)};
\addplot[mark=none, black, ultra thick,dotted] coordinates {(0,5) (5,5)};

\node at (axis cs:2.5, 1.8){default};
\node at (axis cs:2.5, 2.8){thick};
\node at (axis cs:2.5, 3.8){very thick};
\node at (axis cs:2.5, 4.8){ultra thick};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In text you use glyphs of a font, so a dot it easy, but in tikz you have to draw; and squares are easier and faster to draw than circles. The answers in the linked question show this.

Comment: The line styles come from TikZ I think, hence the tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a TeX or any TeX package issue but how PDF specifications are defined. `pgfplots` relies on TikZ and TikZ relies on PS/PDF instructions that are finally used inside the end result.

Dotted and dash-dotted lines are short lines drawn on and off very much like a TikZ decoration. For example if you add `line cap=round` you see the difference.