# Chemfig is drawing out of the box, on my text

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, chemistry

I'm trying to make a figure to show hydrogen bounds. But the figure, draw using chemfig and tikz, but the figure overlaps the surrounding text.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[10]


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \schemestart
  \draw (0,0) node {\chemfig{H-@{doublet}\charge{[circle]270=\|,340=\|}{O}-[:75]H}}
   (340:3) node [rotate=-20] {\chemfig{{@{hydrogene}H-\charge{[circle]270=\|,340=\|}{O}-[:75]H}}};
  \schemestop
  \chemmove{\draw [dashed,-] (doublet.340)--(hydrogene.160);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Schématisation d'une liaison hydrogène dans l'eau}
\label{fig:liaisonH}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

As the chemfig/tikz code is obviously not perfect, any help to improve it is welcome. My primary concern is about the overlap between the figure and the text.

[image: overlap between text and figure]

Edit: I found an unsatisfaying way to get it right: I added `\vspace{1cm}` before the picture and the caption. And then it almost looks like what I want:
[image: no more overlap]
I would prefer: the figure centered, and if someone wants to correct the figure, the dashed line should go from O to H.

Comment: What should it look like in the end and why are you using a tikz enviroment. The problem is chemfig is already laoding a tikz enviroment and uses it´s commands. That is I think what causes the problem.

Comment: @Roland I would like to draw the H-bound, and make a picture with some extras as compared to pure chemfig... As written page 36 of the chemfig manual: "10 Using \chemfig in the tikzpicture environment
It is possible to call the \chemfig inside a tikzpicture environment", followed by an example mixing tikz code and chemfig, so I tried something alike...

Comment: Ah I see so it is possible to call chemfig commands in tikz enviroment.

Comment: Why are you calling a `\schemestart` are you making a reaction scheme?

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/577565/134144

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the combination of a tikz enviroment with `\schemestart` and `\chemove` seem to cause the problem, I simply added an invisible arrow and removed your nodes (they were not necessary).

The figure is now centered and the dashed line goes from the O to H molecule.

You can adjust the angle between the two molecules as you please by changing the value in `\setchemfig{arrow angle=<value>}` and the distance by changing the value in `\arrow{0}[,<value>]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[10]
    

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
        \setchemfig{arrow angle=-5}
        \schemestart
        \chemfig{H-@{doublet}\charge{[circle]270=\|,340=\|}{O}-[:75]H}  
        \arrow{0}[,2.5] 
        \chemfig{{@{hydrogene}H-\charge{[circle]270=\|,340=\|}{O}-[:75]H}}
        \schemestop
        \chemmove{\draw [dashed,-] (doublet.340)--(hydrogene.160);}
    \caption{Schématisation d'une liaison hydrogène dans l'eau}
    \label{fig:liaisonH}
\end{figure}


\lipsum[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can make the job easier if you create a separate figure for the molecules and then insert the figure into the text. In this way, the overlap between figure and text will not occur.

```
\documentclass[margin={2mm 2mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
            \chemfig{H-\charge{344=\|, 254=\|}{O}(-[:76]H)-[:344,3,,,,dotted]H-\charge{344=\|, 254=\|}{O}(-[:76]H)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]