# How to draw dashes and pipe lines in latex and add text below them

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I am trying to draw this diagram in latex, but I am not successful. I am new to latex. I look over SO and internet but I couldn't find any relevant code to draw this structure successfully.
I found these SO links 
[Draw a dash-dotted line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327982/draw-a-dash-dotted-line) and [How to draw a line of dots in tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25642/how-to-draw-a-line-of-dots-in-tikz) , but they are not completely helful

[image]

I tried something like this

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick,dash dot] (0,1) -- (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which results in

```
---.---.---.---
```

but I am unable to add pipe symbol. although i try to use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

But it didn't work for me as well.
If someone help me or guide me how to draw this diagram. I would be grateful.

Comment: Hi, welcome. It's always appreciated if you show how far you've come. In other words, so that the question is "I've gotten this far, how do I do the rest", instead of "how do I do this from scratch". https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333261/ might give you some more inspiration, as well as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31100/. (I know, these are all just bits and pieces, and not necessarily all of them, and they need to be put together correctly. But that's often the case when looking for things like this. Anyway, if no one else answers, I can do that later today, no time right now though.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks a lot for your kind response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

bar symbol is defined in `arrows` or better use `arrows.meta` library:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, dash dot, Bar-Bar] (0,1) -- (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**edit:**
it seems that you looking for this:

[image]

in above image are not used `Bar`s but drawn short vertical lines for `ticks`. for more concise text below number on line is used trick for reduce line spacing. so far i change font family only for text below tick labels (-1, ... 1). but this is simply change.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    LT/.style = {% Label Text
                 text width=22mm, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=1mm,
                 align=center, font=\small\sffamily\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
                 below
                 }
                        ]
\def\faktor{4} % define distance between ticks
    \draw[densely dotted]   (-\faktor,0) -- (\faktoe,0);                        
    \foreach \i/\j in {-1.0/strong negative relationship,
                      -0.5/, 
                       0.0/weak or non relationship,
                       0.5/,
                       1.0/strong positive relationship}
    {
    \draw    (\faktor*\i,1mm)  -- ++ (0,-2mm) node[LT] {\i \\ \j};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for help. I try like this and it works. \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, dash dot, Bar-Bar] (0,1) -- (3,1);
\draw [thick, dash dot, Bar-Bar] (0,1) -- (6,1);
\draw [thick, dash dot, Bar-Bar] (0,1) -- (9,1);
\draw [thick, dash dot, Bar-Bar] (0,1) -- (12,1);
\end{tikzpicture} .. but I need to add text as well as i mention in the question. .

Comment: ah, i then miss read a question ... you like to solution for image, but for it you not need draw `Bar`s, i will edit answer asap.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I mention the image i want to draw in latex. .It would be great if someone help me a bit as i am new to latex.

Comment: @robbin, i reproduce your image in `latex`. see, if it provide what you like to achieve.

Comment: I accept your answer Thanks a lot. it works perfectly fine.